# Ambiguous reference to member 'tableView' using RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, rx-swift

[tableView ambiguous reference error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0PAK.png)

I am facing this error like many of you faced already. I have following code in my UITableViewController:

```
import Foundation
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa

class DiscoveryViewController : UITableViewController {

// MARK: - Properties
let viewModel = MFMovieListViewModel()
let disposeBag: DisposeBag = DisposeBag()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupBindings()
}

// MARK: - Rx binding
private func setupBindings() {
    self.viewModel
        .movies
        .bind(to: tableView
            .rx
            .items(cellIdentifier: MovieListCell.DefaultReuseIdentifier,
                                   cellType: MovieListCell.self)) {
            (row, movie, cell) in
            cell.configure(with: movie)
        }.addDisposableTo(self.disposeBag)       
}
}
```

View Model looks like:

```
import Foundation
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa

class MFMovieListViewModel {

// MARK: - Properties
lazy var movies: Observable<[MovieListMDB]> = {
    return MFAPIClinet.sharedInstance().popularMovies()
}()   
}
```

Don't think it's related to Xcode 8.3 or OSX 10.12, but still tried restarting but nothing is resolved. Appreciate any help provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. DefaultReuseIdentifier wasn't defined in the MovieListCell. :)
Funny error message though!